# Add a optional white space between characters in a string

Tags: regex

I have a string For Exampe

```
string SampleString = "F456-G12345-9090-GHI"
```

I need to add a optional white space between all characters in the above string.

The above string needs to match the same string which may or may not have the white space between ewach character. The other string will be like

```
string samplestring1 = "F456-G12345- 9090  -GHI"
```

Thanks
Padma

Comment: Could you elaborate on the string in general. For example, is it groups capital letters and numbers separated by spaces and dashes? This would help build a more flexible and concise expression.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive that I'm understanding what you'll be matching.  If you're looking for a specific string, then the easiest way is probably to substitute all white space for '' across the string and then do the match.

In perl I'd do:

```
$string =~ s/\s//g;
while ($string =~ m/F456-G12345-9090-GHI/g) {
  # Do something
}
```

If you're looking for multiple strings, and not just a specific one, you might just want to add \s as a potential match [\w\s-]+

However, if you're going to be matching against a specific string, I'd just toss the whitespace whole cloth first rather than performing an expensive regex checking for (and discarding) any whitespace found before checking the string.

Comment: I need to compare the string F456-G12345-9090-GHI with the same string in txt file. But some times the string in the txt files comes in multiple lines . For example F456-G12345-9090-GHI becomes F456-G12345-9090-GHI. i need to check if F456-G12345-9090-GHI == F456-G12345-9090      -GHI

Answer (score 0):

you will probably have to add `\s*` between each character. (or other control characters for whitespace)

```
\s*F\s*4\s*5\s*6\s*-\s*G\s*1\s*2\s*3\s*4\s*5\s*-\s*9\s*0\s*9\s*0\s*-\s*G\s*H\s*I\s*
```

Or, depending on your regex dialect, you might be able to pass an option to ignore whitespace in the source text, but it would depend on which regex library you're using.